# Join 4 tables that have same id laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 4 table : `user`,`education`,`family`,`work`

Table user :

```
id_user | name | address |province|tlp|
---------------------------------------
1       |andi  | xxx     | xxy    |123|
```

table education :

```
id_education | id_user | year |school |
---------------------------------------
1            |   1     | 1990 | aaa   |
2            |   1     | 1994 | bbb   |
```

table family :

```
id_family  | id_user | name   |status |
---------------------------------------
1          |   1     | ddd    | wife   |
2          |   1     | eee    | first children   |
3          |   1     | fff    | second children  |
```

table work :

```
id_work | id_user | year |place |
---------------------------------------
1       |   1     | 2004 | ggg   |
2       |   1     | 2010 | hhh   |
```

I wanna get all of the data in the tables that has sama `id_user`

```
public function show($id) {
    $user = DB::table('user')            
        -> join('education', 'user.id_user', '=', 'education.id_user')
        -> join('family', 'user.id_user', '=', 'family.id_user')
        -> join('work', 'user.id_user', '=', 'work.id_user')            
        ->where('id_user', '=', $id)
        ->first();
    return View::make('user.show')->with('user', $user)->with('title', 'Show User');
}
```

but it gives me error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id_user' in where clause is ambiguous
```

please kindly help me,
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.. ->where('user.id_user', '=', $id) ..`